# In python how to jump to next code if user does not give input in a fixed time?

Tags: python, timer, user-input

I am trying to make a program that prompt the user for input in a cycle. If user does not give input in a fixed time, it should somehow stop asking for input and again give a new prompt.
I have tried the Timer function from threading but in it after the given time is over it does not execute the next code until an input is given.
How to make such a function, please guide me.
Is there any direct way to stop the "input()" process.

Comment: Are you trying this on windows or linux?

Comment: Did you search? Quite a few Q&A's using `python input timeout site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

I tried something with msvcrt on windows

```
import msvcrt
import time

def countdown(time_sec):
    while time_sec:
        mins, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            print("entered ",msvcrt.getch().decode('ASCII'),"so now i will quit")
            break       
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        time_sec -= 1

countdown(5)
```